# Ajuda no Unpivot

Tags: sql, pivot, bigquery

Bom dia pessoal, estou com os seguintes campos no banco de dados `id_negocio,  Dt_PreQualificacao, Dt_Qualificacao,     Dt_Orcamento,    Dt_Negociacao,   Dt_Agendamento,  Dt_PgtPrimConsulta,  Dt_PrimConsulta,     Dt_AgndExames,   Dt_ResultExames,     Dt_RetEspecialista,  Dt_NegFechado,   Dt_Cirurgia,     Dt_RetAmbulatorial,  Dt_FechCiclo,    Dt_NegPerdido,`
[image: Imagem de um select]

Preciso criar um pivot, ou unpivot para transformar neste formato:[image: formato desejado] onde o "id_etapa" é cada uma das linhas iniciadas em "Dt_" , e a data_atividade é o valor de cada campo "Dt_". Preciso apresenta-las em um painel no powerbi contabilizando quantos negócios estavam na etapa X no dia Y.
Alguma dica?

Comment: Um union do tipo .... select 1 fase,dtprequa data_ativ  from tabela union select 2 fase,dtqualif data_ativ from tabela union select 3 fase,....

Comment: É, o jeito foi criar um Union pra cada etapa, inflou muito o Código e não ficou dinâmico, se originarem mais etapas teremos que fazer manutenção manual, porém funcionou, se alguém tiver uma solução mais compacta e dinâmica.. agradeço

Comment: Pivot e unpivot em geral tem este problema dos elementos ficarem "chumbados" o código pode ser enxuto criando uma view que poderia partir da tabela de metadados de table_columns